# How to keep data value intact?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute, jquery-data

I have this basic HTML:

```
<div id ="div1" data-pagenumber="0001">First page</div>

<div id = "div2"></div>
```

and my jQuery:

```
var number = $('#div1').data('pagenumber')

$('#div2').append(number);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JabUS/

Why is the text inside `div2` set to `1`?  It seems to me like jQuery auto converted my value. How do I prevent this conversion so it prints like this, `0001`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use:

```
var number = $('#div1').attr('data-pagenumber');
```

because from [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5):

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise
>   it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string
>   without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JabUS/1/)**

But actually you should be fine if you use jQuery version 1.8+.